# How to report RESTful Web Service endpoint stats from Nginx

Tags: php, rest, nginx, statsd

Is there any tools to collect metrics and analytical data of every RESTful endpoints in Nginx like below show image.

[image: Endpoint Popularity and Response & Error Counts]

Comment: I guess you can better use some util like Logstash for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a commercial solution here: 
https://www.nginx.com/products/live-activity-monitoring/

Or a common open source solution here: 
https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack